# How to disable Google Chrome's Cache?

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, caching, browser

I am modifying a WordPress site's appearance (minor modifications) but can't see the result on chrome because of annoying persistent cache. I tried shift+refresh but it doesn't work. how can i disable the cache temporarily or refresh the page in some way that I could see the changes?

thanks.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development

Answer (score 2):

You should **not** modify your code to achieve this.
If you are using Google Chrome as you said you should press `Ctrl+Shift+j` and go to Network tab. Check the `Disable cache` option and reload the page. Browser will display the response from the server (not from cache).